# Unique value in the list

Tags: python, list, pygame

now I'm creating a minesweeper-alike game in pygame. I'm trying to make bomb numering creator, but unfortunately i'm having list index out of range error. My idea is to generate all 1 numbers, and then when coordinates are the same for i place in the list, change picture to 2 etc.

```py
import sys, os
import pygame
import random
import time

from pygame import mixer

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

W, H = 400, 400

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("mine")

emp_place_img = pygame.image.load('emp.png').convert_alpha()
emp_place_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(emp_place_img)
bomb_img = pygame.image.load('bomb.png').convert_alpha()
bomb_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(bomb_img)
mark1_img = pygame.image.load('mark1.png').convert_alpha()
mark2_img = pygame.image.load('mark2.png').convert_alpha()
mark3_img = pygame.image.load('mark3.png').convert_alpha()

kursor = pygame.image.load('coursor.png').convert_alpha()

kursor_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(kursor)

emp_place_x = []
emp_place_y = []
emp_place_image = []
emp_place_masking = []

placex = 0
placey=0

bomb_image = []
bomb_masking = []
bomb_x = []
bomb_y = []

mark_image = []
mark_masking = []
mark_x = []
mark_y = []
mark_x_pos = [-25,-25,-25,0,0,0,25,25,25]
mark_y_pos = [-25,0,25,-25,0,25,-25,0,25]
mark_blit_number =0

boom = False
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
def emp_place_blit(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(emp_place_image[i], (x, y))
def bomb_blit(x,y,i):
    screen.blit(bomb_image[i],(x,y))
def mark_blit(x,y,i):
    screen.blit(mark_image[i],(x,y))
def main():
    global boom, emp_place_image, emp_place_img, emp_place_x, emp_place_y, placex, placey,mark_blit_number
    running = True
    while running:
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        playerx1, playery1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for i in range(256):
            emp_place_image.append(emp_place_img)
            emp_place_masking.append(pygame.mask.from_surface(emp_place_image[i]))
            emp_place_x.append(placex*25)
            emp_place_y.append(placey)

            placex+=1
            if placex==16:
                placex=0
                placey+=25

        for i in range(256):
            distance = (playerx1 - int(emp_place_x[i])), ((playery1 - int(emp_place_y[i])))
            result = emp_place_masking[i].overlap(kursor_mask, distance)
            if result and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                emp_place_image[i] = pygame.image.load("fill.png")
                if boom == True:
                    sys.exit()
        for i in range(20):
            bomb_image.append(bomb_img)
            randomposx = (random.choice(emp_place_x))
            bomb_x.append(randomposx)
            randomposy = (random.choice(emp_place_y))
            bomb_y.append(randomposy)
            for x in range(9):
                mark_x.append(randomposx+mark_x_pos[x])
                mark_y.append(randomposy+mark_y_pos[x])
                mark_x_add = mark_x
                mark_y_add = mark_y
                mark_x_add_value = mark_x[i]
                mark_y_add_value = mark_y[i]
                mark_x_add.remove(mark_x[i])
                mark_y_add.remove(mark_y[i])
                if mark_x_add_value in mark_x_add and mark_y_add_value in mark_y_add:
                    mark_image.append(mark2_img)
                else:
                    mark_image.append(mark1_img)

        for i in range(20):
            distancebomb1, distancebomb2 = (playerx1 - int(bomb_x[i])), ((playery1 - int(bomb_y[i])))
            if 0<distancebomb1<25 and 0<distancebomb2<25 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                boom = ""
        for i in range(256):
            emp_place_blit(emp_place_x[i], emp_place_y[i], i)
        for i in range(180):
            mark_blit(mark_x[i], mark_y[i], i)

        for i in range(20):
            bomb_blit(bomb_x[i], bomb_y[i], i)

        screen.blit(kursor,(playerx1, playery1))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(60)

main()
```

I'm aware this is probably not the best way to do this minigame, but I want to know what is going wrong and how to repair it
[Basicly this is how the game work(in the final game there just will be a layer above it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0AjV.png)

[image: [1]]

Comment: That's a lot of code and you haven't even told us *where* the error is thrown. Please help us help you by creating a minimal, reproducible example with clearly defined input as well as desired and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mark_x_add = mark_x` does not create a copy of the list `mark`. To create a shallow copy of a list you can use do `mark_x_add = mark_x[:]`. See [Shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Further more, the control variable in the inner loop is `x` rather than `i`:

```py
mark_x_add = mark_x[:]
mark_y_add = mark_y[:]
mark_x_add_value = mark_x[x]
mark_y_add_value = mark_y[x]
mark_x_add.remove(mark_x[x])
mark_y_add.remove(mark_y[x])
```

---

Anyway, you overcomplicate things. The random positions for the bombs have to be computed before the main application loop. So the positions for the marks can be computed before the loop, too. Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store the positions of the bombs and marks. e.g:

```py
grid_size = (16, 16)
field_size = (25, 25)
number_of_bombs = 20
bombs = {}
markpos = [(x, y) for x in range(-1, 2) for y in range(-1, 2) if x != 0 or y !=0]
marks = {}

def main():
    global bombs, marks

    # create random bombs
    while len(bombs) < number_of_bombs:
        bx, by = random.randint(0, grid_size[0]-1), random.randint(0, grid_size[1]-1)
        if (bx, by) not in bombs:
            bombs[(bx, by)] = bomb_img

    # find marks
    for pos in bombs:
        mposlist = [(p[0]+pos[0], p[1]+pos[1]) for p in markpos
                    if 0 <= p[0]+pos[0] < grid_size[0] and 
                       0 <= p[1]+pos[1] < grid_size[1] and
                       (p[0]+pos[0], p[1]+pos[1]) not in bombs]
        for mpos in mposlist:
            marks[mpos] = marks[mpos]+1 if mpos in marks else 1

    running = True
    while running:
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        playerx1, playery1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for x in range(grid_size[0]):
            for y in range(grid_size[1]):
                screen.blit(emp_place_img, (x*field_size[0], y*field_size[1]))

        for pos, img in bombs.items():
            screen.blit(img, (pos[0]*field_size[0], pos[1]*field_size[1])) 

        for pos, count in marks.items():
            img = [mark1_img, mark2_img, mark3_img][min(count-1, 2)]
            screen.blit(img, (pos[0]*field_size[0], pos[1]*field_size[1])) 

        screen.blit(kursor,(playerx1, playery1))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(60)
```

---

> how can i add more marks for 4, 5 etc bombs?

You have to change the line:

```py
img = [mark1_img, mark2_img, mark3_img][min(count-1, 2)]
```

Create a list of mark images somewhere at the initialization part. e.g:

```py
mark_list = [mark1_img, mark2_img, mark3_img, mark4_img, mar5_img]
```

and select the proper image. e.g:

```py
for pos, count in marks.items():
    img = mark_list[min(count-1, len(mark_list)-1)]
    screen.blit(img, (pos[0]*field_size[0], pos[1]*field_size[1]))
```

Comment: woah man, that's a lot of work from your side. Thank you for expanding my knowledge

Comment: So, in your code how can i add more marks for 4, 5 etc bombs?

Comment: @witolo See the last section of the answer, which I've added right now.